# Simulator vs Physical Device: NavigationLink broken after one use

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating an iOS app with SwiftUI. I'm using:

- Xcode Version 11.3 beta (11C24b)
- iPad Simulator running iOS 13.3
- Physical iPad running also iOS 13.3

However, the app behaves different on the two devices. For example on the physical iPad, `NavigationLink` can only be used once.

[image: This is how it looks on the physical device (NavigationLink is broken after first use)]
[image: And on the simulator it works perfectly]

It is my first iOS app. So I'm wondering how these kind of errors can be circumvented or resolved?

```swift
import SwiftUI

enum ExerciseType: String, CaseIterable, Codable, Hashable {
    case vowels = "Vowels"
    case special = "Special Characters"
    case small = "Small Characters"
    case long = "Long Vovels"
}

enum LessonType: String, CaseIterable, Codable, Hashable {
    case hiragana = "Introduction to Hiragana"
    case katakana = "Introduction to Katakana"
    case kanji = "Introduction to Kanji"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Default Lesson")){
                    List{
                        ForEach(LessonType.allCases, id:\.self){ lesson in
                            NavigationLink(destination: LessonView(), label: {Text(lesson.rawValue)})
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("iPad NavigationLink")
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct LessonView: View {
    var body: some View{
        Form{
            List{
                ForEach(ExerciseType.allCases, id:\.self){ exercise in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(exercise.rawValue), label: {Text(exercise.rawValue)})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your table view code.

Comment: Sure, I added some example code that does not work on the real iPad

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/395130

Comment: "_Physical iPad running also iOS 13.3_" ... do you mean iPadOS? :D

Answer (score 2):

The bug is fixed by Apple in iOS 13.3 beta 4. Keep in mind that iOS 13.3 was in beta at the time you tested it. It was not a bug in iOS 13.2, so this is nothing to worry about anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Xcode 11.3 (11C29)

It's fixed when running on iOS 13.3 device, but not on iOS 13.3 simulator.