# SwiftUI: Stepper Binding is not working in the subview

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, swift5

I have a stepper control in the main list view as well as in the detail view. the code is exactly the same. However the stepper in main view is working perfectly, but the subview is stopping after 1 increment (as it looks like the upper bound is set.) The funny thing is it was working some time ago, after improvements, i am not able to trace what exactly changed it s behaviour.

Here is the code.

```
struct QuestionCardTest: View {
    @Binding var question : SurveyQuestion

    var body: some View {

        NavigationLink(destination:QuestionCardDetailTest(question: $question)){
            HStack(spacing: 0){

                Text(question.questionText)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(self.question.ScaleInt) ")
                Stepper(value: self.$question.ScaleInt, in: 0...100)   {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
        }
    }
} 

struct QuestionCardDetailTest: View {

    @Binding var question : SurveyQuestion
    var body: some View {
        VStack
            {
                HStack{
                    Text("Answer (Numeric)")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(self.question.ScaleInt)")
                    Stepper(value: self.$question.ScaleInt, in: 0...100)   {
                        Text("")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this on an actual connected device, as opposed to just the simulator. There have been some weird bugs in the simulator around NavigationLink behaviors that may or may not have been fixed. I have noticed it in my own code when running it on a simulator vs. and actual device for thinks like Pickers and Steppers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217265/navigationlink-freezes-when-trying-to-revisit-previously-clicked-navigationlink/59291574#59291574 and similar problems. The moral is, before you assume it is a coding problem, run it on device.

Comment: Works fine here. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2. I created simple `struct SurveyQuestion` with two properties and `ContentView` with one link in navigation view... that's it. The reason seems somewhere else, not in provided code.

Comment: I tested on both simulator and the actual mobile.  I have created a small app and retested and yes it is working. so i dont know how to debug the entire code

Comment: After spending 8 hours straight I found the reason. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867013/swiftui-list-refresh-scrolls-up] Be careful when you give id to your lists.