# XCode doesn't include files to build on iOS 13.3

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, ios13.3

I just updated my iPhone to iOS 13.3 and now I'm unable to build a simple react native app, I tried to download the newest XCode version (XCode 11.3 beta) which supposed to include the files but it doesn't.

macOS Mojave 10.14.6
[image]

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: How is that related to React Native?

Comment: Someone seems successful working with iOS 13.3 here: [Simulator vs Physical Device: NavigationLink broken after one use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075206/simulator-vs-physical-device-navigationlink-broken-after-one-use)

Comment: please quote the error for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126948

Filed a bug report, no answer yet, will update when more information.

**Update:**

Got feedback from Apple Support, not sure what's exactly happened there:

> Xcode 11.3 contains the iOS 13.2 SDK, which supports iOS 13.3 development.  However, you cannot set a deployment target of 13.3.  Please set a deployment target of 13.2 if you want to support the latest features.

Comment: Apple just don't care ... it is very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

You should add device support for iOS 13.3 in Xcode device support folder. Then quit Xcode and relaunch it.

You can find the file from the below link.

https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport