# SwiftUI - List Navigation not working on an iPhone

Tags: listview, swiftui, navigationview, navigationlink

I got a `NavigationView`, trying to navigate into a `NavigationLink` for a second time without luck.

[image: img]

So `A` then `B` then `A` works fine. Tho `A` then `A` dose not work. The only way to get into `A` is to go to `B` first...

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(documents) { document in
            NavigationLink(destination: DocumentView(document: document)) {
                Text(document.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Testing on an iPhoneX running 13.3. Works fine in the simulator.

Comment: please provide some code so that we can help you....

Comment: @Chris I added the code.

Comment: ok, sorry, can only test 13.2 - that worked.

Comment: try add id in ForEach ?

Comment: @q8yas unfortunately `id` did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple people including me have experienced this issue with the latest version of iOS ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061298/cant-select-same-row-twice-in-swiftui/59119167#59119167) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075206/simulator-vs-physical-device-navigationlink-broken-after-one-use)). It seems to be a bug with iOS 13.3.